# Jmeter: using a Beanshell Assertion to test a null JSON value

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

SI'm trying to test a JSON value that may be = null.

First I tried using jp@gc - JSON Path Assertion. but that doesn't appear to return anything or define the variable if it encounters a null value.

So I was trying to get it to work like this:

- use jp@gc - JSON Path Extractor to try to extract the value to a variable.
- use Beanshell Assertion to test to see if the variable exists or has a null value
- If the variable does not exist, or exists and has a null value, I know that the JSON value was null.

I haven't written any scripts with Jmeter before, so I may be doing something obviously wrong, but here is what I've tried in the Beanshell Assertion:

```
try {
  String myValue = vars.get("myValue");
  log.info("myValue =" + myValue);
}
catch (e) {
  log.info( "caught exception: "+e );
  String myValue = null;
}


if (myValue.length() > 0  && myValue != 0 ){
 Failure = true;
 FailureMessage = "myValue was " + myValue + ".";
}
else{
  Failure = false;
}
```

For this test, a null value actually passes the test.

The problem I'm running into is that the try/catch block doesn't work. Instead, I see the following message in the log:

```
jmeter.assertions.BeanShellAssertion: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils; try {   //myValue = JMeterUtils.get . . . '' : Attempt to resolve method: length() on undefined variable or class name: myValue
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and/or how to get this test of a null JSON value to work?

Comment: Can you show the response from server?

Answer (score 3):

There are many wrong things in this code;

1. The error message says that it does not recognize `myValue`. That's because it is defined within the try-catch block. To fix, you have to declare `String myValue` before the try-catch block. But...
2. Turns out, you don't need the try-catch block after all, since `vars` won't throw any Exception but [will return null when the given key does not exist](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get%28java.lang.String%29).
3. To check if `myValue` is not null, use `myValue != null`.

Here's the updated code:

```
String myValue = vars.get("myValue");
if(myValue != null){
  log.info("myValue =" + myValue);
  Failure = true;
  FailureMessage = "myValue was " + myValue + ".";
}else{
  //log something here?
  Failure = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to amend your code.

1. [Beanshell is not very Java](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell), all clauses will be processed unless you explicitly specify it.
2. Your `myValue` string isn't defined, you need to make it more "global"

Correct code will look as simple as follows:

```
    String myvalue = vars.get("json");

    if (myvalue == null) {
        Failure = false;
    } else if (myvalue.length() > 0) {
        Failure = true;
        FailureMessage = "Expected \"myvalue\" to be null, Actual: " + myvalue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/

Since v.1.2.1 of jp@gc - JSON Path Assertion it is possible to validate against null value. It's not stable version at the moment of writing this comment, though.
It can be downloaded from here: http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/#Developer-Snapshots