# Verify query was filtered using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, assertions

I'm still pretty new to Jmeter.  One of my tests asks for a query that is filtered by type (for this example) using an HTTP request.  The filter asks for only results that are of type "test".  I want to verify that every result returned is of type "test", and that no result outside of that type is returned.  If I give an assertion response using 'contains' with "type": "test", it will only look to see if that is located in the results (only needs to see it once).  I want to make sure it is the ONLY type in the results (looks at what's to the right of every 'type').  If it makes more sense this way, here's a way of doing it using Python.

```
f = open(results)
content = f.readlines()
f.close()

for line in content:
    if "type" in line:
        assert "test" in line, failed
```

Is there a way of doing this using Jmeter?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this kind of thing in any of the programmable assertion elements.

`BSF assertions` allow you to write `jpython` scripts, which is probably most familiar to a python programmer, but there are a range of languages to choose from, including java, ruby and groovy as well as other script languages like perl.

You can access the `SampleResult` object in your code to perform the tests and assertions, then set the `AssertionResult` appropriately.

Comment: Awesome! Unfortunately, though, I just found out that all of our stacks are down and I can't even run a test :/ with that being said, I have a few questions that will probably pop up tomorrow. Does $SampleResult contain the results? (so will `print $SampleResults` print all of the results).  Python/Jython doesn't use the $ when using variables, so can you use just SampleResult as a variable?  Finally, you said to set the AssertionResult.  Is there something built into Jmeter for that? Or do I have to write my own assertion?

Comment: actually, looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713272/jmeter-using-a-beanshell-assertion-to-test-a-null-json-value , I can prob figure out how to do it.  Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped, i don't use python in jmeter, so can't answer those questions. SampleResult and AssertionResult are jmeter objects, passed to the script as arguments, with methods to manipulate attributes.